# Android adb shell am broadcast: Bad component name

Tags: android, adb, bootcompleted

I am trying to 'emulate' a reboot (or anything else with the `adb shell am`) and am unable to figure out how to reference my component.  Then again, maybe I don't even understand what is meant by a component.  Below I first include a few example commands that don't work, then my manifest.  Note that StartupReceiver is successfully called when the 'phone' boots.  I just want to re-trigger it without a full reboot.

Failed ADB commands:

```
$ ./adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED -c android.intent.category.HOME -n net.fstab.checkit_android.StartupReceiver
<help snipped>
Error: Bad component name: net.fstab.checkit_android.StartupReceiver

$ ./adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED -c android.intent.category.HOME -n .StartupReceiver
<help snipped>
Error: Bad component name: .StartupReceiver

$ ./adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED -c android.intent.category.HOME -n StartupReceiver
<help snipped>
Error: Bad component name: StartupReceiver
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="net.fstab.checkit_android" android:installLocation="internalOnly"
    android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".BaseActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="BasePreferences" />
        <activity android:name="EditActivity" />

        <receiver android:name="StartupReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <receiver android:name="NotificationReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="net.fstab.checkit_android.NotificationReceiver" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name="StartupService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="net.fstab.checkit_android.StartupService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You need to specify the package name before the class name (then you may write it without the package) like this:

```
./adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED -c android.intent.category.HOME -n net.fstab.checkit_android/.StartupReceiver
```

Practically it turns out that you just have to add a slash after the package name.

You helped me start, I helped you finish :)

Comment: *grrr*  a dot delimited hierarchy with a random slash thrown in there!  *boggle*  regardless, i'm glad you found my post useful and were able to help me out too.  thanks.

Comment: Is this now broken in Android 8/9?

Answer (score 61):

Broadcast does not require specify any Receiver.
This case, please just stroke

```
adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 11):

Some apps may misbehave if BOOT_COMPLETED is received twice, instead limit broadcast to your app only:

```
adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED -p com.example.package
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

`adb shell am broadcast \
-a android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED \
-n net.fstab.checkit_android/.StartupReceiver`

(note the **-n net.fstab.checkit_android/.StartupReceiver**) to aim at a specific receiver.

Also make sure your app uses permission to receive specific broadcast intents - in this case it would be

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />`